# How to assign one variable value to new variable value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, angular5

I trying to creating a new dynamic array. I assigned one dynamic variable value to another new variable and pushing new array. But updating last array variable value.

### Code

```
for(let i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){              
            let categories = allItems[i].categories;
                for(let j=0;j<categories.length;j++){
                    let categoryId = categories[j].id;
                    //console.log("categories[j].id ", categoryId);
                    allItems[i]['categoryId'] = categoryId;
                        reitems.push(allItems[i]);

            }
}
```

### My Json Value:

```
[{

    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "itemDesc" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "itemId" : 1,
    "unitId" : 2,
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "text" : "single room"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "text" : "Foyer/Living"
        } 
    ]
},
{
....
}]
```

### Output

```
[{

    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "categoryId " : 2
},
{
    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "categoryId " : 2
}]
```

### Expecting Output

```
[{

    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "categoryId " 1
},
{
    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "categoryId " 2
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it will work.

```
let allItems = data;
        let reitems = [];
        let n = 0;
        let allItemCategory = data.categories;


            for(let i=0; i<allItems.length; i++){
                allItems[i].categories.forEach(element => {
                    console.log('element.id',element.id)

                    let categoryId = element.id;

                    var obj = {
                        categoryId : element.id,
                        itemName : allItems[i].itemName,
                        itemDesc : allItems[i].itemDesc
                    }

                    reitems[n] = obj;
                    n++;
                });

            }

            console.log('allI new reitems ------->', reitems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with shallow copy, it is assigning reference of array.

Use angular.copy(source, destination) for deep copy.

```
  var allItems = [{
    "itemName" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "itemDesc" : "3 SS Finish Baskets",
    "itemId" : 1,
    "unitId" : 2,
    "categories" : [ 
      {
        "id" : 1,
        "text" : "single room"
      },
      {
        "id" : 2,
        "text" : "Foyer/Living"
      } 
    ]
  }]
  $scope.reitems = [];
  for(let i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){              
    let categories = allItems[i].categories;
    for(let j=0;j<categories.length;j++){
      let temp = {};
      angular.copy(allItems[i], temp);
      temp['categoryId'] = categories[j].id;
      $scope.reitems.push(temp);
    }
  }
```